# PHP Load Testing framework

Tags: php, testing, open-source, load

Anyone know of an opensource PHP Load Testing Framework similar to the Grinder " "http://grinder.sourceforge.net/".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used the grinder, but It sounds similar to [JMeter](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/). Also at times I have used plain old [Selenium](http://selenium-rc.openqa.org/) for load testing.

Answer (score 1):

RedLine has a [Cloud Load Testing](http://www.redline13.com) tool in PHP on Amazon AWS now.  it is free for the service, but you have to pay for the Spot Instances on your account (for example 50,000 user test on 200 m1.small is about $2/hour).